# PHP foreach loop in TCPDF and forced download

Tags: php, foreach, header, tcpdf

```
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

$pdf->AddPage();

$html = '<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->lastPage();

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
$pdf->Output();
```

Guys I'm using tcpdf to output a PDF invoice. Problem is how do I foreach loop into the $html above that tcpdf provided?

And my forced download header doesn't seems to be working. It doesn't pops up a window asking me to save the file.

The array contains orderno, product, qty, total

Comment: nothing special about tcpdf use foreach() as you would else where

Comment: the foreach loop will be within the $html or outside or it?

Comment: quite possibly both! spooky eh

Answer (score 4):

Concatenate your content into the `$html` variable using the `.` concatenation operator:

```
$html = '<table>';

foreach($your_data_array as $key => $current) {
    $html .= '<tr>
        <td>' . $current['your_var'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $current['another_var'] . '</td>
    </tr>';
}

$html .= '</table>';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

As for forcing download, have a look at these articles on StackOverflow:

- [Force download PDF created by TCPDF, after Ajax post submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962325/force-download-pdf-created-by-tcpdf-after-ajax-post-submit-solved)
- [How to download PDF File Generated from TCPDF (PHP) using AJAX (jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500485/how-to-download-pdf-file-generated-from-tcpdf-php-using-ajax-jquery)

... and [the manual](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1):

> D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.

```
$pdf->Output($filename, 'D');
```